# What tools are available to create a help file in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, chm, helpfile

I need to write a help file for a WinForms app in Visual Studio 2010. Ideally, I'd like to use a tool that integrates with Visual Studio, rather than a totally separate tool.

In the past I've used HTML Help Workshop, but this is ancient, and I recall it was a little funky to use. I also know there was a tool built into the Visual Studio 2005 SDK, but I need something for 2010.

Comment: What do you imagine "integrates" ? Context sensitive help popups?

Comment: @Macro - I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to author and compile help files using Visual Studio.

Comment: What topics or content will be in the help file: End-user/UI topics? Or software/API topics?

Comment: @ChrisW - end user topics. This would be a CHM or other format (HTML, PDF, etc) file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is an awkward target for tool vendors.  In most shops, the help is authored by professional writers that don't have any use for Visual Studio in their day-to-day activities.  Third party authoring tools like RoboHelp is their preferred weapon of choice.

The VS2005 SDK tool you probably saw was [HelpStudio Lite](http://www.innovasys.com/products/hslite/overview.aspx?cpid=vssdk), a product of Innovasys.  There is no version available that integrates with VS2010 and judging from a [forum post](http://www.innovasys.com/cs/forums/t/631.aspx) they have no intention of releasing one.  Their Document X! product however does, sounds like what you ought to take a look at.  The eval version is available for download [from here](http://www.innovasys.com/download/eval.aspx).

Comment: Adobe FrameMaker 12 has built-in tool for generating CHM as well so, in general, it can convert XML files (that can be made in VS) to CHM.

Answer (score 13):

**Here are your options...**

If you want Microsoft's documentation generator with VS integration:

- [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) for help file generation
- [DocProject](http://docproject.codeplex.com/) to integrate it into VS

*Although, it appears that [DocProject doesn't quite support VS2010 yet](http://docproject.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=209179).*

For the Non-MS solution there's [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx), which **does** support VS 2010 integration and appears to be a better solution.

For options that don't integrate into Visual Studio:

- [DoxyGen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)
- [Docu](http://docu.jagregory.com/)
- [NDoc3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndoc3/)

Comment: Sandcastle may be good for documenting APIs, but not for documenting applications GUIs; don't you agree?

Comment: @ChrisW No application that generates documentation from comments extracted directly from the source does, because WinForms/WPF applications typically don't include comments in the auto-generated Designer/XAML files. I assumed that, since the question is geared toward auto generating docs, the OP is looking to create a 'Software Users Manual' and not a general 'Users Manual'.

Comment: @ChrisW nice close-ended suggestive question though.

Comment: @EvanPlaice - does ghostdoc *actually* produce .chm/.html help files though?

Comment: @Micky Duncan: GhostDoc Pro does.

Answer (score 5):

I remember that a year or so ago some people on Joel's The Business of Software forum were recommending [HelpNDoc](http://www.helpndoc.com/).

Forum discussion: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?biz.5.359131.10

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can convert the triple slash XML MSDN-style help using Sandcastle on all class-level members and objects

```
/// <summary>
/// I am a method help Header
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parm1">info for param 1</param>
/// <param name="parm2">info for parm2</param>
/// <remarks>Some Extra Info</remarks>
public override void MeMethod(SourceElement rootElm, Subject subject){
...
```

Here is the link to [Sandscastle](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E82EA71D-DA89-42EE-A715-696E3A4873B2&displaylang=en)

A **more feature-rich** help generator that **integrates with Visual Studio 2010** and generates multiple help formats is [VSDocMan](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) .  It includes a WYSIWYG comment editor, and actually comments some of your code for you.  Extremely useful

Answer (score 1):

ghost doc with documentx or sandcastle is the way to go...Rest is all still very primitive when it comes to 2010. If you have project both c# and C++ then documentx will be the way if its just C# then any one is good.

Answer (score 1):

If the audience for your help file is the user of the application html help 2 is not usable, you will still need to create a chm file. The tool which can do this for your from your winforms application is [Help Generator for Visual Studio](http://www.helpgenerator.com/help_and_documentation_for_visual_studio_net_applications.htm), which takes away a lot of work in preparing the help and linking it to the forms.

Answer (score 0):

Probably doesn't integrate with VS2010 but I remember using RoboHelp back around '97 and it was ok:ish then so if I needed to write helpfiles now I'd probably give that another look since it seems like it's still around [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/robohelp/). Fairly expensive though it seems but if you've got some Adobe licenses (which isn't totally unsual for a development shop) for some other reason maybe you've already got this?

Answer (score 0):

Html Help, is replaced by  Html Help 2.

http://www.mshelpwiki.com/wiki/tiki-index.php?page=Help2

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Just been doing a lot of research and after testing various tools the http://www.helpgenerator.com/ is the fastest way to put together a help system.