# Is there a way to automate compiling HTML Help files?

Tags: build-automation, chm, html-help

I'm working on writing a build script for the installer for this: http://github.com/imaginationac/belvedere.

The installation package includes help in the .chm format. I can manually compile with Microsoft HTML Help Workshop, but from reading over the documentation, there doesn't seem to be any way to, say compile from the command line. I did a quick Google search (and a search here) and haven't found an exact solution (or one that would NOT cost money).

If I have to prompt builder to do it manually, it's not that big of a deal, but it does put a kink in the whole automated build script idea.

The gist of the question is: is there a tool like Microsoft HTML Help Workshop that could integrate as part of an automated build process?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not exactly sure what I did wrong before, but the hhc.exe file IS actually the compiler, and I got it working from the command line. I must have messed up the command earlier. :(

For reference:
`hhc.exe PATH\TO\HELP\PROJECT\project.hhp`

Answer (score 0):

You can build it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Which version?

Comment: Visual Studio 2005 comes with HelpStudio Lite. Visual Studio 2010 removed HelpStudio. For more information, read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077361/what-tools-are-available-to-create-a-help-file-in-visual-studio-2010