# How to make help file for our Windows C#.net application?

Tags: c#

I have task in my project,I want to develop a help file(f1) for my project,i dont have any idea how can i achieve this task please help any one.

Comment: Have you done eny research? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms669985%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Google is your friend, and so is searching stackoverflow!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077361/what-tools-are-available-to-create-a-help-file-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 2):

You can create some **HTML** pages and then convert them into a **CHM** file , When user press F1 , try to open it , That all you should do

Good Luck